# How to receive confirmation emails in realm SDK(Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, email-confirmation

1.I'm trying to use realm react-native sdk。
2.In the realm settings, i set `Send Confirmation Email` or `Confirmation Function` options。
3.when i call `app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser({ email, password })`
I did not receive the email。
4.Then I tried different email addresses。
5.Try calling `callResetPasswordFunction` `resendConfirmationEmail` `resetPassword`
I still did not receive the email....

Comment: From the docs - *The Email Confirmation URL should point to a page that contains an email confirmation script. The user's token and tokenId will automatically be appended to this URL in the email. The URL must include a scheme, such as http or https.*